# YII php framework localhost works but 127.0.0.1 does not

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm following a book "Agile Web Application Development with Yii" and I am setting up a database connection to the Yii application through an application component.

I followed the books instructions and said the mysql db host is 127.0.0.1.  I ran a test and it failed to connect.

Then I changed the host to "localhost" and it works.

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: Maybe a IPv4/IPv6 issue. What IP will be pinged at when you ping localhost? 127.0.0.1 or ::1?

Comment: when I ping localhost the ip that is pinged is 127.0.0.1

Comment: That is strange. Sorry no idea.

Comment: check two files: `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/my.cnf` - see if there's anything wrong with the configuration of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: /etc/hosts has the following:

127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost

Comment: could it be related to your mysql server access only allowing localhost not 127.0.0.1?

Comment: works for me, are you sure this wasn't a typo?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it isn't a typo.  In main.php I have 'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=trackstar_dev'

Answer (score 1):

Check the file name host at this location

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc
```

Check the default value of localhost in the host file, by default it should be `127.0.0.1` if not, change it to `127.0.0.1`. Now try to access your wamp server by using 127.0.0.1 on any web browser.

Comment: I am using a mac with mountain lion.  I am able to access the MAMP web server on the browser with 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this problem: [Mysql localhost != 127.0.0.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712307/mysql-localhost-127-0-0-1)

Socket is used when `localhost`, while tcp/ip is used when `127.0.0.1`.