# Mysql localhost != 127.0.0.1?

Tags: mysql

```
$ mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -e 'show tables' created_from_host;
+-----------------------------+
| Tables_in_created_from_host |
+-----------------------------+
| test                        |
+-----------------------------+

$ mysql -u root -h localhost -e 'show tables' created_from_host;
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'created_from_host'

$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```

How could it be? And main question - **how to grant ALL privileges on ALL databases from ALL hosts for root?**

**UPD:**

```
$ mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -pzenoss -e "show grants";
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*3715D7F2B0C1D26D72357829DF94B81731174B8C' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
$ mysql -u root -h localhost -pzenoss -e "show grants";
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*3715D7F2B0C1D26D72357829DF94B81731174B8C' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**UPD2:**

```
zends> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'skip_networking';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| skip_networking | OFF   |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

zends> SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user WHERE user='root'; 
+------+-----------------------+
| user | host                  |
+------+-----------------------+
| root | 127.0.0.1             |
| root | ::1                   |
| root | localhost             |
| root | localhost.localdomain |
+------+-----------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: what do you get from $ ping localhost ?

Comment: @kery 64 bytes from localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.029 ms

Comment: then the issue is probably with your grants.  You need to grant privileges to 'root'@'localhost' or something like that

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually asking, but yes mysql treats localhost and 127.0.0.1 differently. localhost applies to connections from the local host over an IPC mechanism, such as unix domain sockets. 127.0.0.1 applies to TCP/IP connections from the local host. The same will happen when you run the mysql command line tool, -h localhost uses a unix socket to connect, -h 127.0.0.1 uses TCP/IP. These could potentially make you connect to different mysql server instances too..

Answer (score 14):

As you can see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html), a UNIX mysqld uses sockets if used without a host name or with the host name `localhost`.

So it makes a difference, and in the GRANT system this difference becomes evident.

Answer (score 14):

I know this tread is old, however was most probably not correctly answered.

By default, mysql does a name resolve so 127.0.0.1 and localhost will resolve in the same. However, you can switch the name resolution off in my.cnf:

skip-name-resolve       = 1

Then localhost and 127.0.0.1 will *NOT* be the same anymore. So you either keep the name resolution, or restrict yourself to only using localhost in your grants or only 127.0.0.1
BUT: If you do the latter one, you will have to access our database with those credentials as well.

Comment: Actually, I think this answer is wrong. The issue with mysql and localhost vs. 127.0.0.1 is that mysql treats localhost differently in that it uses a unix socket connection and not tcp. Which means, user hosts 127.0.0.1 and localhost in GRANTs are NOT resulting in the same.

Answer (score 11):

Log in through 127.0.0.1 and execute this statement:

```
SHOW GRANTS
```

You will probably see something like

```
GRANT ALL ... 'root'@'127.0.0.1'
```

I just confirmed on my local install and it seems MySQL won't auto-resolve the host name. You can either add another grant for `localhost` or just use 127.0.0.1

Comment: Grants look just the same for every host, but databases which localhost and 127.0.0.1 could access is different.

I updated the "screenshots" in question to ilustrate this.

Answer (score 1):

This caused issues in setting up a local dev environment on MacOS.

Several script functions, say `mysqli_connect()` in php might be using `localhost` to connect to MySQL: You can't (shouldn't have to) go about replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` in every script.

Tried fixing this by adding `bind-address=localhost`, `socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock`, `socket=/tmp/mysql.sock` etc. to the my.cnf file, but that didn't work.

**To resolve the issue** (on MacOS), note that the `mysql.default_socket` setting in `/etc/php.ini` file points to `/var/mysql/mysql.sock`, while MySQL's default_socket is `/tmp/mysql.sock`.

So, either edit your `php.ini` file, or create a softlink to MySQL's default_socket:

```
mkdir /var/mysql
ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

P.S - 127.0.0.1 is treated as a TCP connection and localhost as unix socket connection by MySQL: details [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html).