# mysql user@host_id submet: wildcard vs ip mask?

Tags: mysql, admin

What is the difference between

```
CREATE USER 'bob'@'123.456.789.%'
```

and

```
CREATE USER 'bob'@'123.456.789.0/255.255.255.0'
```

and also in `GRANT` statements?

Other than the potential for spoofing in the first command, which mysql now guards against, what is the difference?

I've read the mysql docs on the subject but I'm still confused about a few things. Could someone provide a pointer to a discussion contrasting/comparing them?

Comment: That should, of course, be 'wildcard'.

Comment: What are the "few things" you're mentioning?

Comment: localhost vs 127.0.0.1 is another. But I found an [explanation of that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712307/mysql-localhost-127-0-0-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much a handy shorthand, though not recommended in the MySQL doc itself. The wildcard effect is the same in GRANT statements.

You'd have more flexibility with the long version to specify shorter network ranges tho.

MySQL protects against abuse such as a connection from:

```
'123.456.789.2.example.com'
```

So you might imagine future abuse with special characters in the domain name, taking place of the last digit. That's subject to a lot of comments btw!

Comment: Yeah, your answer's much better than mine. I'll just delete it.