# Laravel 5.4 - Custom Artisan Command "Access is denied."

Tags: laravel

So I made a custom `artisan` command that will dump an sql file from my database.

Here's what is inside the command.

I named it `db:dump` with this syntax:

```
protected $signature = 'db:dump';
```

Next is the command itself:

```
public function handle()
    {
        $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $host = env('DB_HOST');
        $username = env('DB_USERNAME');
        $password = env('DB_PASSWORD');
        $database = env('DB_DATABASE');

        $ts = time();
        $path = database_path() . $ds . 'backups' . $ds . date('Y', $ts) . $ds . date('m', $ts) . $ds . date('d', $ts) . $ds;
        $file = date('Y-m-d-His', $ts) . '-dump-' . $database . '.sql';
        $command = sprintf('mysqldump -h %s -u %s -p\'%s\' %s > %s', $host, $username, $password, $database, $path . $file);
        if (!is_dir($path)) {
            mkdir($path, 0755, true);
        }
        exec($command);
    }
```

So all of the info needed are inside my `.env` file. If it would help, I'll also provide what's inside it:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:3WuXKyS70VX+V/Ic5QjuVcmFbzsqTkJehiQA7q9s9gk=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_salesandinventory
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

With that info, everything's ready and hopefully it could have worked.

But whenever I execute the command in my command prompt:

`php artisan db:dump`

It always says **"Access is denied."**

I lost any lead here, I don't know what could be the problem.

**EDIT:** When I replace the command with just `$this->info('TEST');` it will work. It's like a console.log command or some sort. What I wanted to say is that there's something wrong in my command that restricts me from doing it.

Comment: Can you print the command instead of executing it, then paste that into command line? Does that work?

Comment: @Anders What do you mean? I'm sorry, I'm totally lost with that. xD

Comment: instead of exec($command) do dd($command). Copy paste the printed string and test it out in your command line.

Comment: `mkdir($path, 0755, true);` change it to `mkdir($path, 0777, true);`, See what happens.

Comment: @Anders I copy and pasted the command from `dd($command)` but it still says "Access is denied."

Comment: @Gammer "Access is denied." is still showing. May I know what those numbers are for? :o

Comment: Ok, so then this has nothing to do with laravel. Start writing a correct mysqldump call that works in your command line. Not sure how to do that. Good luck!

Comment: Okay restart your local server. and check again.

Comment: @Gammer Do you mean by restart... close my xampp servers and artisan serve?

Comment: Just artisan serve.

Comment: @Gammer still doesn't work. "Access is denied" is still there.

Comment: Okay it seems the issue of mysql dump, Check it

Comment: @Gammer I'm thinking maybe that my path isn't accessible? Or some privilege options maybe in my folders?

Comment: That is also can be case.

Comment: Run the command using -v flag, which will give you more details.

Comment: What did `dd($command)` show? If that does not work, the problem is access to the database - your host, user, or password are wrong.

Comment: It showed me this `mysqldump -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p'' db_salesandinventory > C:\Users\Jan Mark San Jose\Google Drive\salesandinventory\database\backups\2017\09\11\2017-09-11-173912-dump-db_salesandinventory.sql`

Comment: What's the permissions on the `artisan` file? Try running as root and see if that fixes it (I'm not suggesting you always run as root, but if running as root works then it's a file permission issue probably).

Comment: @apokryfos I'm sorry but what does it mean to "run as root?".

Comment: On Ubuntu I'd do `sudo php artisan db:dump` probably works for most Linux distributions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the problem and did some alternative ways to prevent it.

Unfortunately, I cannot access my `C:\Users\PCNAME\` and my project is saved there. I'm trying to dump the database inside the project path but it can't be accessed.

So as an alternative, I changed the path of where it will be dumped, I set it to `C:\salesandinventory\backups\`

Here's the whole code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class MySqlDump extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'db:dump';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Runs the mysqldump utility using info from .env';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $host = env('DB_HOST');
        $username = env('DB_USERNAME');
        $password = env('DB_PASSWORD');
        $database = env('DB_DATABASE');

        $mysqlpath = 'C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump';

        $ts = time();
        // $path = 'database' . $ds . 'backups' . $ds . date('Y', $ts) . $ds . date('m', $ts) . $ds . date('d', $ts) . $ds;
        $path = 'C:\salesandinventory\Backups' . $ds . date('Y', $ts) . $ds . date('m', $ts) . $ds . date('d', $ts) . $ds;
        $file = date('Y-m-d-His', $ts) . '-dump-' . $database . '.sql';
        $command = sprintf($mysqlpath . ' --user=' . $username . ' --password=' . $password . ' --host=' . $host . ' ' . $database . ' > ' . $path . $file);

        if (!is_dir($path)) 
        {
            mkdir($path, 0755, true);
        }

        exec($command);
    }
}
```

The bottomline is, there's a problem with my folders with it being not accessible. I still don't know why, I tried opening command promt as an **Administrator.** But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, you describe that the command your script is generating and trying to execute is (as seen when you `dd($command)` instead of trying to `exec($command)`):

```
mysqldump -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p'' db_salesandinventory > <output-file>
```

where `<output-file>` is in your home directory so presumably writable.  You also mentioned that running that command manually fails with the same permissions error.  So the problem has nothing to do with Laravel, but your access to your MySQL server.

First of all test if your username and password are correct.  Try, on your console:

```
mysql -u root -p db_salesandinventory
```

(without `-h`).  You will be prompted for a password, enter the one you are using in your script.  If it does not work, you are using the wrong u/p, fix those and try your script again.

If it *does* work, it means your root user is not allowed to connect to `127.0.0.1`.  For MySQL, `localhost` is not the same as `127.0.0.1`, and you'll need to enable access for your `root` user using that IP, [as described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712307/mysql-localhost-127-0-0-1).

Comment: @Jan Ariel San Jose did this help?