# mysql setup in digital ocean using node express

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, express, digital-ocean

I just decided to switch from google sql to hosting my own mysql server on the droplet where my app is because google sql is so expensive for a side/start up project.

anyway, my problem is, i don't know how to connect to mysql using my app. I can access the mysql using the terminal, i've also manage to setup it on workbench but i can't get the app to connect to it.

this is my config object

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 
DB_USER=root
DB_PASSWORD=*****
DB_NAME=express_mysql_database00
```

Questions:

1. List item are these all i need?
2. it the db host correct?
3. i'm using the mysql module, do i need to use a different one to make this work?

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: none, thanks for the fast response man. I've solved this by making the db host as local host.

Comment: Have a look at my answer. If it satisfies your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [readme of the `mysql` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql), those are the parameters you need (there are a lot more parameters where you most likely the default value is suitable for you):

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret',
  database : 'my_db'
});
```

> it the db host correct?

That depends on how you configured the database. There is a difference between `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`. See: [Mysql localhost != 127.0.0.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712307/mysql-localhost-127-0-0-1)

> i'm using the mysql module, do i need to use a different one to make this work?

Looks like this is one you can use...

Comment: thank you sir for answering my question, but i just solved it a few seconds ago :)  use the default host and restart nginx

Comment: @Don https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work