# Can't connect to remote mysql (with PuTTY and tunnel)

Tags: mysql, putty, remote-server, portforwarding

I'm trying to use mysql on a remote Debian server. I have configured PuTTy client with a tunnel:

- In `Session` , Host name is the remote IP address , and port is 22
- In `SSH/Tunnels` I have source port 3306 and Destination: 127.0.0.1:3306

I click open, type the user name and password to log in to the server.

But at this point I can't use mysql. If I try this with no password:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

I get `access denied for user 'root'@localhost' (using password: NO)`

I am not sure if this is because there really is some password needed or if there is something wrong with the port forwarding - how can I know?

I tried going in to the `my.cnf` file and change the `bind address      127.0.0.1` to the remote address instead, but there was no change. Maybe mysql needs to be restarted for that, but I get access denied when trying to restart it (the same mysql error message).

I can see in the puTTY event log that it says `"local port 3306 forwarding to 127.0.0.1:3306"`. A bit further down it says `"Opening connection to 127.0.0.1:3306 for forwarding from 127.0.0.1:55271"` - I don't know what that's about?

How do I know if the issue is with the password or if it's with the "`@localhost`" part, were there is something wrong with the port forwarding?

Comment: The error says you are not using a password on your root account. Try `mysql -uroot`

Comment: Be careful in using "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" in MySQL, they are different thinks when checking logins. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712307/mysql-localhost-127-0-0-1

Comment: Which mysql client are you trying to use? The one in Debian or the one in Windows? Why you need a tunnel?

Comment: The debian mysql I guess. I thought I would need a tunnel since mysql is configured to listen for 127.0.0.1. But after changing the "bind address" to my local IP, maybe I don't need a tunnel, I don't know.

Comment: I mean  changing the "bind address" to the remote IP..

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have either forgotten what your root password was, or you never set it up .. Either way you're going to need to set / reset it.

If you have access to `ssh` (which your post suggests you do), and you have `sudo` access .. This should be a snap.  Issue the following commands:

Stop your MySQl process  .. Most Debian systems will be

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Then start MySQL safely without password:

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

Then log in as `root`

```
mysql -u root
```

Set the password for `root`

```
use mysql;
update user set password=PASSWORD("PASSWORD") where User='root';
flush privileges;
quit
```

Then restart mysql

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

At this point, you should be prompted for a password when you issue the command:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: I can't do sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables because  MySQL daemon is still running, but I can't stop it with /etc/init.d/mysqld stop because I get the "access denied" error..

Comment: You'll need to `sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld stop`

Comment: Allright I tried it but it seems to restart right away: [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.5.54-0+deb8u1) starting as process 13164 ...

Comment: did you try `sudo service mysql stop` ?

Comment: Yes I do that first, then sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld stop

Comment: I could stop the mysqld process with "killall mysqld mysqld_safe". Now I can use mysql, so the problem was the password.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you do not need a tunnel.
By default mysql install will allow access from localhost without password. The ssh session is remote, but mysql session would be local, so you do not need to change bind address.

Unless your Windows IP is public and reachable from Debian and you have installed MySQL client in Windows properly you still have a couple of less complicated options than a tunnel.

Just start ssh and enter `sudo mysql` and you should be fine, however, depending on your ssh user and mysql user -and his privileges- you would need to adjust the `-u` and `-p` parameters.

Have you run the `mysql_secure_installation` command?

Comment: I have not run that command , I could look into it. So the problem is really with the password? So I need to reset it..

Comment: Maybe, it really depends on how mysql was installed (package, bundled, LAMP, compiled) and what have you done. Have you (or anyone else) been prompted to set mysql root password?.