# Unable to connect to mysql server with go and docker - dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused

Tags: mysql, database, docker, go, docker-compose

I have Mysql Community Server installed on my mac, it is set up and is working, I can connect to it on localhost:3306 using Navicat for MySQL. However, whenever I try and connect to the database from my go app which is running using docker-compose, I get the following error:

```
dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused
```

This is my go code:

```
// dbUser, dbPassword, & dbName are all variables that definitely contain the correct values
db, err = sql.Open("mysql", dbUser+":"+dbPassword+"@tcp(localhost:3306)/"+dbName)

if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

defer db.Close()

query, err := db.Query("INSERT INTO test_table(test_field) VALUES(This is a test)")

if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

defer query.Close()
```

and I am importing:

```
"database/sql"
_ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
```

Any help would be really appreciated, thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712307/mysql-localhost-127-0-0-1

Comment: This has been asked and answered before. Check [connecting from docker VM to host.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't connect to `localhost` from Docker (especially on a Mac, where Docker runs in a Linux VM under the surface) and expect to access the services provided by the host machine.

However, there is functionality to access the host machine by IP address using the special hostname `docker.for.mac.localhost`. Absent any other Docker networking issues, amending your connection string to use `docker.for.mac.localhost:3306` should resolve this issue and permit access to services on the host machine.

(More details about this workaround available in the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/docker-for-mac/networking/#per-container-ip-addressing-is-not-possible).)

Comment: This works, thank you :) And thank you for the explanation. I am guessing because this is a workaround that I shouldn't be doing it this way, what is the proper way to develop with MySQL using docker-compose? (I am very new to docker)

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with this approach. It has the benefit that your database data persists – i.e. the data won't go away if you destroy a MySQL container accidentally, nor do you have to worry about mapping a host volume into such a container, which is more complex. The alternative would be to host a MySQL instance in Docker and set this up using Docker Compose in the same way. You gain Docker's internal container-to-container networking capabilities at this point. The main benefit of `docker.for.mac.localhost` is the Docker daemon will map that name to the host IP automatically.

Comment: Thank you for this, I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 9):

You should open like this:

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:root@tcp(mysql:3306)/GoLife")
```

`mysql` is docker-compose service name.

Answer (score 1):

My solution ended up being a combination of the answers on this page. I was receiving the error:

```
dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused
```

And my connection was constructed like so:

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql",  "root:password@/mydbname?parseTime=true")
```

I read what @Cosmic Ossifrage had wasn't sure how to implement it so i applied the answer given by Vitah. this did not work because mysql:3306 was not a location that docker understood so connection failed. I then applied @Cosmic Ossifrage's solution with Vitah's to get a working setup.

```
db, err:= sql.Open("mysql", "root:password@tcp(docker.for.mac.localhost:3306)/mydbname?parseTime=true")
```

Hope this helps anyone searching for the answer! Thank you to the other contributors for helping me piece it together

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to handle this is using the [docker iptables](https://docs.docker.com/network/).

If your `docker-composer.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
    api:
        container_name: webapi
        restart: on-failure
        depends_on:
            - mariadb
        ...
   db:
        image: mariadb
        container_name: mariadb
        volumes:
            - database:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        ...
```

You can use the `container_name` of the `db` service like this.

```golang
func main() {
  dsn := "user:pass@tcp(mariadb)/dbname?charset=utf8"
  db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})

  if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
  }
}
```

Super easy, this is recommend if you `db` service has a dynamic IP.

Answer (score 0):

i used my local machine ip address to fix the issue , this is to connect to my mysql server running on my local from a docker-compose