# way to configure `localhost` to mean only `127.0.0.1` (or turn off IPV6) in Mac OS Catalina

Tags: macos, networking

I'm working on a Mac OS Catalina and have problems when a client is configured to localhost; I believe that it's only trying to reconcile to only the IPV6 address and not IPV4. As an example, this:

```
irb(main):004:0> $redis = Redis.new(host: 'localhost')
=> #<Redis client v3.2.2 for redis://localhost:6379/0>
irb(main):005:0> $redis.set('drink','water')
Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Redis::TimeoutError)
```

but works fine if specified as 127.0.0.1. I have the same issue with Memcached.

One implication would be different semantics for things like MySQL where localhost and 127.0.0.1 mean distinct things but that is an outlier (for example this [Mysql localhost != 127.0.0.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712307/mysql-localhost-127-0-0-1) ).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a larger issue, but if you just want to turn off IPv6.

1. Open System Preferences > Network.
2. Select the active network adapter (Wi-Fi or Ethernet ) from the left panel.
3. Click on the Advanced button from the right panel.
4. Next, click on the TCP/IP tab.
5. Select the Configure IPv6 drop-down menu and set it to Off.
6. Click the OK button.
7. Restart your Mac to make sure the IPv6 is disabled.

Comment: thx - I probably should've mentioned that I had done that. I'm really trying to turn of the renociliation of locahost to an IPV6 address at the software stack level. It appears some people have had similar issues before such as this https://github.com/petergoldstein/dalli/issues/21 (btw, I have also tried commenting out the /etc/hosts line). Very frustrating as I have to run custom branches of multiple gems looking for 'localhost' and then changing it to 127.0.0.1

Comment: From Mojave on this option was hidden in the GUI, use the CLI instead
`networksetup -setv6off "Wi-Fi"`
(or any other interface from `networksetup -listallnetworkservices`)
or try to remove the address via `sudo /sbin/ifconfig lo0 inet6 ::1/128 remove`. While this will remove ::1 from lo1 it won't clear the DNS entry of localhost from ::1 :-(
check via `host localhost`