# Why is it possible to connect to MySQL 8 via CLI but not via an application?

Tags: mysql

I somehow can not connect with my python application to a new MySQL server on localhost. The pw seems to be OK as I can login, but the application can not.

Grants:

```
mysql> show grants for test@localhost;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for test@localhost                                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `test`@`localhost`                                   |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `Project`.* TO `test`@`localhost` |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Logfile:

```
2021-02-11T10:49:13.897580Z    10 Connect   crawler@localhost on Project using SSL/TLS
2021-02-11T10:49:13.897736Z    10 Connect   Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

BUT, I can connect from CLI:

```
$ mysql -u test -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 11
Server version: 8.0.23 MySQL Community Server - GPL
```

Logfile:

```
2021-02-11T10:51:48.590555Z    11 Connect   test@localhost on  using Socket
2021-02-11T10:51:48.591527Z    11 Query select @@version_comment limit 1
```

The password contains this string: `42$7&Z` and is 16 char long.

I have set: `default_authentication_plugin= mysql_native_password`  now, but still no change.

Connection from Python 3.8 (works on other servers):

```
def create_connection(self):
    settings = get_project_settings()

    self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=settings.get('MYSQL_SERVER'),
        user=settings.get('MYSQL_USER'),
        passwd=settings.get('MYSQL_PW'),
        database=settings.get('MYSQL_DB'),
        charset='utf8'
    )
    self.conn._time_zone = '+00:00'
    self.conn.autocommit = True
    self.curr = self.conn.cursor()
    self.curb = self.conn.cursor(buffered=True)
```

Is there something I have overlooked?

Comment: for what I remember mysql 8 uses a different method for handling passwords compared to previous versions. Look for instructions on how to update your pyton code for mysql server 8. Or check how to enable the compatibility mode for passwords to have mysql use the legacy method

Comment: Right, I remember. Set this now to: default_authentication_plugin= mysql_native_password but even after restarting the server it is the same

Comment: Please share more details - how do you try to connect in your application?

Comment: I added parts of the code to the question. This works on other systems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql localhost != 127.0.0.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712307/mysql-localhost-127-0-0-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting the MySQL `'test'@'localhost'` user and creating it again (instructions below). Then grant privileges and do not use `get_project_settings()`. Just enter the `str` values.

To recreate the user run these commands:

```
DROP USER 'test'@'localhost';
CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
```

This is the modified code with the `str` values (if that works check your configuration and try again with your code):

```
def create_connection(self):
    self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='test',
        password='password,
        database='database',
        charset='utf8'
    )

    self.conn._time_zone = '+00:00'
    self.conn.autocommit = True
    self.curr = self.conn.cursor()
    self.curb = self.conn.cursor(buffered=True)
```

Comment: I changed the password for the user to not contain special characters and added this to the conf: default_authentication_plugin= mysql_native_password This has fixed the issue and I believe your solution is similar to that approach.