# mySQL through docker compose not available at localhost

Tags: javascript, mysql, docker, docker-compose

I deployed mysql via docker compose and it's available at 0.0.0.0 and at 127.0.0.1 via commands `mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --user=root --password=team6 --port=53366` and `mysql --host=0.0.0.0 --user=root --password=team6 --port=53366` but `mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password=team6 --port=53366` fails due to "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)", why?

My end goal is for this code to work

```js
      con = await mysql.createConnection({
        host:  'localhost',
        port:  '53366', //We need to consider adding new users
        user: 'root',
        password: 'team6',
        database: 'Yahtzee',
      });
```

My compose file:

```yaml
# Compose file for creating a database named Yahtzee in a mysql container
version: '3.8'
services:
  team6db:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: team6
      MYSQL_DATABASE: Yahtzee
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
    volumes:
      - team6db:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./Initdb.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/Initdb.sql
      - ./InsertSampleGameRecords.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/InsertSampleGameRecords.sql
    ports:
      - '53366:3306'

  team6phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - team6db
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: team6db
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: team
    ports:
      - '50086:80'

volumes:
  team6db:
```

Comment: This sort of sounds like [Mysql localhost != 127.0.0.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712307/mysql-localhost-127-0-0-1)  I've observed the `mysql` command-line tool to interpret `localhost` as "via a Unix socket" even though it should be a valid host name, and this can result in different behavior in some places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up having a typo in my connection where I defined my port as "user" within the library I was calling (should have just been passing the connection in but whatever that's a separate problem). Now the tests work fine with localhost as the port but `mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password=team6 --port=53366` still fails with the error `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` while `mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --user=root --password=team6 --port=53366` and `mysql --host=0.0.0.0 --user=root --password=team6 --port=53366` both succeed. I don't understand why and I would like to know but I've been working on this for far longer than I'd like to admit and given my tests work now I'm moving on.